# CRM - Prompt user for input into on demand workflow

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using a CRM Dynamics Workflow with a custom activity to run some code against an entity. I've realised that I need to pass a variable to the custom activity which the user will supply.

It's possible to add a prompt to a Dialog, but Dialogs cannot be run across multiple entities so are unusable for my purpose.

Is there anyway to prompt the user in a workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't possible.  Assuming this fits your use case you'll need to capture and persist to the entity the data from the user via a JavaScript prompt or in a required field on the form and use this value in the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

No, because workflows were designed originally to be asynchronous they have to use pre-supplied values.

What is the value? can you store it on the system user entity? If so you can have the workflow take a look at the user that's executing the command, then grab the value from the system user entity.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of blog posts have pointed me in that direction.